# How to Load image from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I added notifications to my web application.

This is the JavaScript that runs and shows the notifications on the notification bar.

With the notification, I want to show a notification icon for each line.
When I run the program, the image does not show.

**This is how I tried to add the image:**

```js
$("#menu1").append('<li> <a> <span class=image><img src ="~/Theme/production/images/Annon.png"/> </span> <span>' + value.Ndetails + '</li><hr/>');
```

**This is the full code:**

```js
function LoadData() {
  $('#menu1').empty();
  $('#menu1').append($('<li> Loading.. </li>'));
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: $("#Get").val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.Success == true) 
        $('#menu1').empty();
        if (data.listNoti.length == 0) {
          $('#menu1').append($('<li>There is nothing to show </li>'));
        }
        $("#notiCount").empty();
        $("#notiCount").append(data.listNoti.length);
        $.each(data.listNoti, function (index, value) {
          $("#menu1").append('<li> <a> <span class=image><img src ="~/Theme/production/images/Annon.png"/> </span> <span>' + value.Ndetails + '</li><hr/>');
        });
        $("#menu1").append('<li><button onclick="ClearNotifications();"style="border:none;background-color: transparent;"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Clear All Notifications</button></li>')
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: If your image `src` (link) Is correct, the Image will be rendered. Also try to make: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You open many elements which you never close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Looks like you provided bad relative path**

```html
<img src ="~/Theme/production/images/Annon.png"/>
```

**Instead that, try this way**

```html
<img src ="./images/Annon.png"/>
```

- First try to make an individual folder for your project
- Then add all of your assets like images,audio,etc to that folder

**Pictorial reference**:
[click this link to see an example for good relative path](https://stuyhsdesign.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/relative-path.png)

Comment: I tried, but still the same issue

Comment: I found another way to do it, I removed the image and replace it with an icon. Now it's working. Thanks for the help and for trying. :)